# Checking if the values are greater than a certain number in cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I have this div and want to check if all the texts within this div are greater than 800. Is there any way to do this in cypress?

```
<div>
 <div>700</div>
<div>720</div>
<div>810</div>
<div>830</div>
<div>850</div>
</div>


 it("Show cars below 700 euro", () => {
   
    var prices=cy.get("div > div >").should()
   )}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First assign a className for your div, for example `value1`.

```
 <div className="value1">700</div>
```

Then:

```
cy.get(".value1").invoke('text').then(parseFloat).should('be.gte', 800)
```

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming* that doing `cy.get("div > div")` will return you only the elements you want to check, you can simply iterate over the yielded element list, u[sing `.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Yields)

```
cy.get("div > div").each((el) => {
  const text = el.text();
  expect(text).to.be.greaterThan(800);
})
```

If the `div > div` does not uniquely yield only the elements you want to check, you will need to find a different way to uniquely isolate these elements. Adding a className, like Ali suggests, is one way.